# Reading from Excel using PHPExcel in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to read from Excel files in CodeIgniter. Having issues with integrating the following example provided by PHPExcel in their documentations

Here's the code from the example:

```
<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2003XML';
//  $inputFileType = 'OOCalc';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
$sheetname = 'Data Sheet #3';


class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        // Read rows 1 to 7 and columns A to E only
        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 7) {
            if (in_array($column,range('A','E'))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter();

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
echo 'Loading Sheet "',$sheetname,'" only<br />';
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
echo 'Loading Sheet using filter<br />';
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

echo '<hr />';

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);

?>
```

So, integrating the example with CodeIgniter I did the following:

1. Created a function 'importFromExcel()' which is called from a button click in the View.

   ```
   public function importFromExcel() 
   {
   $this->load->library('excel');

   $this->load->library('Excel/MyReadFilter');

   $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
   //  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
   $inputFileName = FCPATH.'uploads/khanas.xlsx';
   $sheetname = 'Sheet1';

   $filterSubset = new MyReadFilter();

   echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
   echo 'Loading Sheet "',$sheetname,'" only<br />';
   $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
   echo 'Loading Sheet using filter<br />';
   $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


   echo '<hr />';

   $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
   var_dump($sheetData);
   }
   ```
2. Created a library in 'application/libraries' and named it 'MyReadFilter.php'

   ```
   class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
   {
   public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
       $startRow   = 1;
       $endRow     = 7;
       $startCol   = 'A';
       $endCol     = 'E';

       // Read rows 1 to 7 and columns A to E only
       if ($row >= $startRow && $row <= $endRow) {
           if (in_array($column,range($startCol,$endCol))) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
   }
   ```

When I call the class as below doesn't work.

```
$this->load->library('Excel/MyReadFilter');
```

How do I go about fixing this?